# Why is Firefox behavior not consistent?

Tags: android, html, css, firefox

I made my photography website as cross platform as I could without making separate web pages. This is [my webpage](http://luis.impa.br/photo).

It validates ok in w3c, and works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox for Linux, and in Chrome, Dolphin and the default browser for Android. However, it goes crazy in Firefox for android phones: it zooms in a lot with no reason, and the formatting is totally wrong.

Of course this is a bug in Firefox since it is not consistent between platforms, but which is the culprit? How can this be avoided? I guess there's something that can be done in the big IMG at the beginning of the page to prevent this.

EDIT: Firefox for tablets works fine too.

Comment: This may be a better fit for http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not really. I'm asking for flexible HTML/CSS tags/style to prevent this kind of behavior.